# If I put entity items into a dictionary and update them there, do they update when I submit changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What I mean is that I have something like

```
var foosById = context.Foos.ToDictionary(f => f.Id, f => f);
foreach(var foo in foosById)
{
   // modify foo.Value, possibly
}
```

and I then run

```
context.SubmitChanges();
```

are the changes reflected? They should be, since my dictionary is a reference to the items, right?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Asking the question is answering it.

Comment: I think too, that RIGHT.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,it should work as expected.If you want you can put the `context.SubmitChanges();` inside the `foreach` loop itself.But it's not a recommended way to do that due to poor performance.So always try to put the `context.SubmitChanges();` out side the loop.

But I would like to recommend you to use `SaveChanges()` instead of the `SubmitChanges()`.

Here is the difference of those 2 methods.

**SaveChanges() -** operates within a transaction. `SaveChanges` will roll back that transaction and throw an exception if any of the dirty `ObjectStateEntry` objects cannot be persisted.

**SubmitChanges() -**  starts a transaction and will roll back if an exception occurs while `SubmitChanges()` is executing. However, this does not roll back the changes in memory or tracked by the `DataContext`.Those changes will need to be rolled back manually.